# How can I return a dataset (which is dependent on my input query) in a PHP web service using nuSOAP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I want to return a data set (whose results are dynamic as it depends on my input parameters) in a PHP web service, using nuSOAP. How do I register my return type since I do not know how many (and what type of) columns and rows will be resulting from my input query.

Comment: You have to be one contract of return type (that can be one array with 1 or n rows). If you don't know exactly the return type maybe REST service will be better.

Comment: @SérgioMichels: I may have to look into the REST service since I haven't come across that yet.

Comment: I got it working by converting the dataset, i.e. the result of my dynamic query, into a CSV with the first record having the names of the fields and the following records as the actual records. Now I can return the CSV which is always going to be a STRING and then convert it into a table at the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by converting the dataset, i.e. the result of my dynamic query, into a CSV with the first record having the names of the fields and the following records as the actual records. Now I can return the CSV which is always going to be a STRING and then convert it into a table at the front end